# Сборка драйвера OCI для Qt

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, qt5

Возникла необходимость подключить Oracle БД к проекту.
Изучил документацию и форумы - начал собирать дрова через mingw

```
set INCLUDE=D:\Program\DB\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\OCI\include;
set LIB=D:\Program\DB\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\OCI\lib\MSVC;
cd D:\Program\Qt\5.2.1\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\oci
qmake oci.pro
mingw32-make
```

Добавил необходимые переменные в Path, проверил все пути - не собирается, лишь выдает пачку undefined reference to
[image: Результат компиляции]
**Qt 5.2.1,
Oracle g 11.2.0,
Mingw4.8 x32**

Кто уже сталкивался с аналогичной проблемой - подскажите или дайте ссылку.

Comment: компилятор mingw, а либы MSVC, если либы не реализуют С интерфейс, то нужны обязательно собранные конкретным компилятором

Comment: @VTT ,клонишь к тому, что надо собирать через nmake от VS?

Comment: Я клоню к тому, что надо бы разобраться с зависимостями.

Comment: Попробуйте без MSVC для библиотек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась установкой MSVC15 и загрузкой соответствующего набора в Qt
+ в самом проекте выбрал оба набора для компиляции драйвера